# Transposing a string in List in python

Tags: python, string, list

I would like to ask if it is possible to "transpose" a list of strings. For example, my inputs are:

```
x = ["___", "aaa", "---", "bbb", "---", "ccc", "___"]
for i in x:
   print (i)
_______
*a*a*a*
-------
*b*b*b*
-------
*c*c*c*
_______
```

I would like to transpose this list of strings into the following output:
(Only the letters will shift but the line seperator.)

```
_______
*c*b*a*
-------
*c*b*a*
-------
*c*b*a*
_______
```

Comment: Are there any restrictions or requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
x = ["___", "aaa", "---", "bbb", "---", "ccc", "___"]

x[1::2] = [''.join(x) for x in zip(*reversed(x[1::2]))]
for i in x:
   print (i)
```

Output:

```
___
cba
---
cba
---
cba
___
```

The `reversed` is there to get `cba` instead of `abc`, which would be the transposed from the other corner.

A bit of explanation:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x[1::2] = [6, 7]  # result x == [1, 6, 3, 7, 5]
```

The slice (`1::2` i.e. starting at the 2nd element with `1`, in steps of `2`) is used to replace only the text, and leave the lines. It's also used to select only the data that's needed for the solution.

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
x = list(zip(*x))  # result x == [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

By zipping the unpacked lists, the 'transpose' is performed. Adding the reversal:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
x = list(zip(*reversed(x)))  # result x == [(7, 4, 1), (8, 5, 2), (9, 6, 3)]
```

The results here are tuples, but that doesn't matter, since you need everything turned back into strings anyway:

```
x = ('a', 'b', 'c')
x = ''.join(x)  # result x == 'abc'
```

All put together, you get the solution provided above.

Edit: you changed the problem, but it's really more of the same. If you weren't able to figure it out, have another close read of the above, because all the parts are more or less there. It gets a bit trickier because you now need to perform the slice and update on strings as well, and it's no longer a single line. But the same idea - if this was homework, try to get it, because not getting it might come back to bite you later.

```
x = ["_______", "*a*a*a*", "-------", "*b*b*b*", "-------", "*c*c*c*", "_______"]

parts = list(map(list, x[1::2]))
for p, r in zip(parts, zip(*reversed([s[1::2] for s in x[1::2]]))):
    p[1::2] = r
x[1::2] = map(lambda x: ''.join(x), parts)
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
_______
*c*b*a*
-------
*c*b*a*
-------
*c*b*a*
_______
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the changes but what if there is additional symbols inside the code. does it still work?

Comment: It's just the same problem again, but with an added level of unpacking. I updated the solution.

Comment: Note that if you keep changing parameters, it may turn out you need another solution altogether - in that case, the takeaway should be that you should ask the question that needs answering, not a solution to a problem you think is the same problem, that leads to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).